# Casting LONG to function pointer?

Tags: c++, windows, function, winapi, pointers

How does this work?

I looked at this tutorial from [here](http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/message_loop.html):

> WNDPROC fWndProc = (WNDPROC)GetWindowLong(Msg.hwnd, GWL_WNDPROC);

From [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633584%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) it explains that GetWindowLong returns a LONG that is defined as just a long. This confuses me because it is converted into a function pointer (WNDPROC).

What happens when you convert a long into a function pointer? They are completely different things. How can the function pointer even work when a long isn't even a function?

Comment: Look at it this way: It starts as a function pointer, gets casted to `LONG` for the return value, then gets casted back to a function pointer.

Comment: You can legally cast back and forth between pointer and an equivalent length integer in C.  It's not guaranteed to work, however, except for the `null` pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pointer is just address of variable; So it is presented by integer.

Standard says `uintptr_t` and `intptr_t` is compatible with pointers

```
#include <stdint.h>
int a;
int *pa = &a;
uintptr_t addr_of_a = (uintpt_t)pa;
```

In 32-bit system, `sizeof(uintptr_t)` = `sizeof(int *)` = `4`. In 64-bit system, they're `8`.

`GetWindowLong` function is used for 32-bit system, so its return value's type is `LONG`, which is 4 byte.

In 64-bit system, however, size of pointer is 8 byte. So microsoft deprecate `GetWindowLong`, and you should use `GetWindowLongPtr` and `LONG_PTR`.

```
// the type of the return value of GetWindowLongPtr is LONG_PTR. So this code is safe and portable.
WNDPROC fWndProc = (WNDPROC)GetWindowLongPtr(Msg.hwnd, GWLP_WNDPROC);
```

Comment: if I say function_ptr = foo; is foo an address or does foo hold a value that is an address for function_ptr to use?

Comment: @user2893243 Seeing is believing. Try this: `#include <stdio.h> void foo() { } int main() { printf("%p\n", foo); }`

Comment: I tried this with integers and was surprised you could set a pointer to an int: `#include <stdio.h>  
int main() {int a = 5;long b = (long)(&a);printf("Value of a: %d, ", a);printf("Address of a: %d\n", &a);printf("Value of b: %d, ", b);printf("Address of b: %d\n", &b);int *c = (int*)(b);printf("Value of c: %d, ", c);printf("Address of c: %d\n", &c);printf("Value of int c points to: %d\n", *c);return 0;}`   I connected this with WNDPROC and long and it makes 1000% more   sense! thanks

Comment: @user2893243 you should use `intptr_t` and `%p`, and `GetWindowLongPtr` for 32/64 bit machine. 64-bit become more and more universal.

Answer (score 1):

On a 32bit Windows, a **LONG** is a 32 bit value, which is the same size as an address. @Chris is right, it starts as a function pointer that gets converted as a long, then you typecast it as a function pointer.

If you look at the notes from MSDN, you'll notice that the `GetWindowLongPtr()` has replaced the original call. It returns a **LONG_PTR**, which is the way Microsoft declares a long that has the same size as a pointer on the current process architecture. Basically, it will be a 32bit address with 32bit processes, but 64bit on 64bit processes.

Answer (score 1):

It assumes you are running on a system where there is a bijection between all possible addresses of a function, and a subset of all non-trap representations of a long.

In other words, so long as there are at least as many possible LONG values as there are WNDPROC values then this can work.

Usually the compiler would just shovel the bits from the WNDPROC into the memory (or register) for the LONG within GetWindowLong, and then shovel them back out into the WNDPROC for the line that you show.